# how can I see POST methods in raw HTTP that my computer sends to a page?

Tags: http, post, methods

that's it

isn't there a way to see the raw text file that my browser sends to a website when I do a POST method?

something like:

POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0 
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32
home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You need a proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/). Fiddler is a freeware HTTP Debugging Proxy which allows you to inspect all HTTP Traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data.

Answer (score 9):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is also a great addition to Firefox that will let you see HTTP traffic as well as lots of other aspects of your pages.

Comment: But it doesn't show the RAW data. It shows everything categorized which, for some applications, is not always for the best...

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little bit of overkill in this instance, but you might want to check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647)

Answer (score 3):

[Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) is a nice Firefox plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

i can't beleive nobody mentioned [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (the tool previously known as Ethereal).  There was also a time when several articles said that every network administrator should have a Mac only to run Etherpeek (now known as [OmniPeek](http://www.wildpackets.com/products/overview), and runs on windows instead of mac)

Comment: I mentioned Wireshark almost 3 hours before you made this post.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) plugin for Firefox

Answer (score 1):

[TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/index.html) is a Java based TCP proxy, not as full featured as Fiddler appears to be, but runs on anything with a JVM.